# how can i perform a query on a hash, and get result another hash?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do a query against a ruby hash, which is much alike this:

`{"client1" => {"tag" => "13", "host" => "client1.example.com", ...}, "client2" => {"tag" => "11", ...} }`

and I would like to map it to only the client names with their tags, like this:

`{"client1" => "13", "client2" => "11"}`

I have been struggeling with .each and .select and .find but haven't figured it out yet. I am pretty sure it is not that hard, does anybody know? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the same as below

```
data = {
  "client1" => {"tag" => "13", "host" => "client1.example.com"}, 
  "client2" => {"tag" => "11"} 
}

desired_data = Hash.new
data.each do |k,v|
  desired_data[k] = v["tag"]
end
```

`desired_data` will contain your result.

As suggested by @sawa you could also use

```
data.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k] = v["tag"]}
```

Comment: Or `data.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k] = v["tag"]}`.

Comment: @sawa good implementation +1. Didn't knew that `each_with_object` works so well with `Hash`. Thanks for the info.

Comment: very nice. I go with the oneliner :) Thanks both

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
test_hash = {"client1" => {"tag" => "13", "host" => "client1.example.com"}, "client2" => {"tag" => "11"} }

test_hash.map{|k,v| [k, v['tag']]}.to_h
#=> {"client1"=>"13", "client2"=>"11"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to merge the hash with itself, using the form of [Hash#merge](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which in this case is all keys.

```
h = {"client1" => {"tag" => "13", "host" => "client1.example.com"},
     "client2" => {"tag" => "11"} }

h.merge(h) { |*,v| v["tag"] }
  #=> {"client1"=>"13", "client2"=>"11"}
```

As explained in the doc, the block has three variables, often written `|key, old_value, new_value|`. Here `old_value` and `new_value` are the same. The asterisk in `|*, new_value|` is a placeholder for all but the last block variable.